# Raylib project stopped being able to run

Tags: visual-studio, game-engine, raylib

Raylib project in visual studio was working perfectly fine, as in if you run the project it would execute and create a window and the game would run, but after opening the project one day, after attempting to run the project the same error kept appearing:
*LNK1104    cannot open file '..\bin\Debug.DLL\ProjectName.exe'*
I've tried rebuilding the project but the same error keeps appearing and I am not sure why.
Any Answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one thing that has worked for me in the past is transferring use into VScode instead of VSstudio, also a linker error is usually file related, check ether your program is already running or is loaded in the debugger(close it and run debug again) or your library paths are incorrect or aren't wrapped in double-quotes(depends on the path, may need < >). would be more clear if you included some code at least the uses of directives.

Comment: okay thanks, switching to visual studio code seems to have fixed the problem